# What are the differences between each virtual console (Ctrl+Alt F1 - F6)?

Tags: terminal, shell, console, virtual-console

In Ubuntu, there are 6 virtual consoles, which can be accessed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F6</kbd>, and <kbd>F7,</kbd> to exit.

What are the differences between these virtual consoles? Do they run different things, such as the GUI? Can I use these consoles?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it stems from the desire to have and switch between multiple foreground applications/logins running at the same time.  Since unix and linux were always designed to be a multi-user and multi-tasking environment from the beginning, before [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) or networking was invented, this was one method used and it is kept because it can be handy sometimes.

Edit:

Short answer: no difference.

A bit more: number 1 is the 1st one and some distro's default to sending system messages to just that one.

Well OK there is a little difference, typically these days the higher numbers are for GUI, and lower numbers for text based interface. Though many distro's use 7-12 for GUIs and 1-6 for text interfaces, not all are like this, some have 1-4 and 5-8 for text/gui and do not assume you have keys F9-F12 as some old keyboards didn't.

Comment: That's actually an answer (albeit a historically inaccurate one) to [the question of why these virtual consoles exist](http://superuser.com/questions/453652/), not to the question asked here which is _whether they are different from one another_.

Comment: ok so I was answering the wrong question.  As for historical accuracy I could be mistaken in my belief, but I'll still believe it until I see documentation that says otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am not experienced enough but I didn't find any difference among tty1 to tty6. However, sometimes I see system messages appear in tty1 after I boot my system.

By the way, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> doesn't `exit`. If you switch back to the tty your were working you will find your session there.